# Comparision of a theorem in Banach Space with Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

We have learnt the following two theorems (*Functional Analysis by J.B. Conway*):

[image: Theorem 1]
and
[image: Theorem 2]
Where $X$ is a normed space and $M$ is a closed subspace.

And we were told that there is a similar result (May be a theorem) when $X$ is a Hilbert Space.
So could you help me to verify that..
I know in Hilbert space we can have $M^{\perp}=\{ x\in X: <x,m>=0, \forall m\in M \}$

I'm not sure whether my question has an exact answer. But I appreciate your opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is. You want to relate the notation $M^\perp$ there with orthogonal complements? If $X$ is a Hilbert space, Riesz's representation theorem says that every bounded linear functional $f\colon X \to \Bbb K$ has the form $f(x) = \langle y_f, x\rangle$ for some unique $y_f \in X$. So the polar space $\{ f \in X^* \mid f|_M = 0 \}$ (which is denoted there by $M^\perp$) is isomorphic to the actual orthogonal complement $M^\perp$.

Comment: Thank you. But do we have a similar result in Hilbert spaces that goes with the second theorem? That is a quotient space which is isometrically isomorphic with $M^{\perp}$

Comment: Hilbert space is a special case of Banach space. Not only do we have a "similar" result, *this* one applies directly. Moreover, one can identify $\mathscr{X}^*$ with $\mathscr{X}$ in the Hilbert case, and yes, the quotient is isometrically isomorphic to the complement.

Comment: So you mean even  for the first theorem.. If we consider the $X^*/M^{\perp}$,  In the case of Hilbert space, although we cannot directly consider the quotient between $X^*$(Linear functionals) and $M^{\perp}$ (A subset of $X$), because they are not subsets it can still make sense as there is a correspondence between the perpendicular elements and the linear functionals that are zero on $M$. Am I correct?

Comment: We *can* consider it directly. Since the inner product canonically identifies $X^*$ with $X$ their subsets are also identified, so $M^{\perp}$ becomes a subset of $X$. Any $x\in X$ defines a linear functional $<\!\!x,>$ on $X$ and vice versa.